# Form validation using ngMessage showing error on load only

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, ng-messages

Here is my form

I am getting weird behaviour. when my form loads This will show you error that 'This is required' when page only load nothing touched.
When I will enter something the message will not vanish It will be there only.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
  <label>{{controlObject.controlValue}}</label>
  <md-icon md-font-icon="" aria-label="{{controlObject.controlValue}}"></md-icon>
  <input type="text" ng-model="controlObject.controlAttribute" name="{{controlObject.controlId}}" ng-required="true">
  <div ng-messages="myForm.{{controlObject.controlId}}.$error" layout-align="end end" layout="column">
    <div ng-message="required" ng-if="myForm.$pristine">This is required.</div>
  </div>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong here. Please let me know how can I resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-show` on `$dirty` or `$submitted`

`<div ng-show="myForm.{{controlObject.controlId}}.$dirty" ng-messages="myForm.{{controlObject.controlId}}.$error" layout-align="end end" layout="column">
    <div ng-message="required" ng-if="myForm.$pristine">This is required.</div>
  </div>`

Comment: Not working .. still error message would be visible on page load only

Comment: Could you make a plunker?